# Would the flipper zero be able to read/communicate with a physical OTP device?

Tags: raspberry-pi, nfc, raspbian, raspberry-pi4, totp

I have a Fettian C200 H27 token, here is the link, click on h27 casing model:
https://www.ftsafe.com/store/product/otp-c200-oath-time-based-totp-token/

I am curious if the flipper zero is able to read this, and if it could, how? I am trying to read the current OTP, it uses TOTP (time based) if it helps. I saw this video right here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=126&v=C0pM6TIyvXI&feature=youtu.be See how he is able to extract the OTP. If this isn't possible is it possible to read the seed or interact with c200 at all? Please let me know if you how to do any of this and be please be patient I am new to this. Thanks :)

If I can't read it with flipper zero is there some module I could use in order to read it with a raspberry pi 4 b+
**note: I'm not sure if stack overflow is the right place for flipper zero content but I saw a few posts here**